# Dataframe Split query

Tags: dataframe, split

I have a dataframe column which contains all the text below in each row

```
Symbol(id=15351, ticker=VXX, market=US, currency=USD, type=EQUITY,tick_size=0.010000, lot_size=100, contract_size=0, rate=None)
```

I am trying to extract only after ticker=, which gives VXX

I tried

```
df['symbolcolumn']  = df['symbolcolumn'].str.split(',market', expand=True)
```

But it does not extract only the symbol ticker

Looking for `df['symbolcolumn'] = VXX`

Can you advise me please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to do it by

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].astype(str)
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.split(', market', expand=True)
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].apply(lambda x: x.split("=")[-1])
```